# Unmet dependencies installing SWI-Prolog

Tags: 18.04, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

When trying to download SWI-Prolog using `sudo apt-get install swi-prolog`, I got a series of errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpython3-dev : Depends: libpython3.5-dev (>= 3.5.1-2~) but it is not installable
python3.5-dev : Depends: python3.5 (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4) but 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3 is to be 
installed
             Depends: libpython3.5-dev (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4) but it is not installable
             Depends: libpython3.5 (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4) but 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3 is to be 
installed
swi-prolog-nox : Depends: libossp-uuid16 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libreadline7 (>= 6.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libedit-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgmp-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libncursesw5-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libreadline-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: debhelper but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I did try `apt-get -f install`, which threw the errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpython3-dev : Depends: libpython3.5-dev (>= 3.5.1-2~) but it is not 
installable
python3.5-dev : Depends: python3.5 (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4) but 3.5.2- 
2ubuntu0~16.04.3 is installed
             Depends: libpython3.5-dev (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4) but it is 
not installable
             Depends: libpython3.5 (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.4) but 3.5.2- 
2ubuntu0~16.04.3 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by 
held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I also have the same problem(s) when doing a full update using `sudo apt-get update` or `upgrade`.  How can I fix these errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106985/discussion-on-question-by-ollie-unmet-dependencies-installing-swi-prolog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question....  I had to make a fresh installation of Ubuntu.  Now on 20.04.